# Powershell Invoke-Command with 7zip Output

Tags: powershell, 7zip, invoke-command

I have a script that I am using to both backup and restore zip files from a network share and I am using the command line 7zip to do it. The first step in the restore process is that I copy to files from the backup location locally to the machine I am going to be restoring the files to. I then run the 7ip command using the remote machine's C:\temp folder as the beginning path and the folder it needs to go to (C:\users\username...) for the ending path. I am using the "-bsp1" to give the percentage output and if I run it directly from my machine to the UNC path, I can control the cursor to stay put and the percentage to continue going up. If I do it remotely, the percentages go down in a line and I have no way of taking the output as a stream and making the percentage stay put.

Here is the code when I do it directly from my machine:

```
& "C:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" "x" $CopiedFolder -o"$RemoteFolder" -aoa "-bsp1" | out-string -stream | Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}%" -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } | foreach {
    [System.Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, [System.Console]::CursorTop) 
    Write-Host -NoNewline "Unzipping [$fold]..."$_
    }  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " Completed"
```

This produces the following:

```
Unzipping [Backup Folder]...10%
```

and it goes up to 100% while staying put.

The issue I have is that it is very slow running 7-zip from my machine to the UNC path of 2 machines and being the "middle man". I would like to run 7-zip directly from the machine that is getting the files moved so that it speeds up the process. I would like the output to look the same, but can't figure out how to make this work with invoke-command. Here is what I have so far and the percentages just go down in a line

```
$Script = {& "C:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" "x" $using:CopiedFolder -o"$using:RemoteFolder" -aoa "-bsp1" | Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}%" -AllMatches  | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } }
Invoke-command -Computer $Adcomp -Scriptblock $Script
```

This is the output:

```
Unzipping [Backup Folder]...0%
0%
1%
2%
3%
4%
4%
4%
5%
6%
7%
8%
9%
10%
11%
12%
13%
```

How do I make it so that the percentage stays right next to the "..."?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe the output of `Invoke-Command` to the `foreach` block you already have in your local code:

```
Invoke-command -Computer $Adcomp -Scriptblock $Script | foreach {
    [System.Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, [System.Console]::CursorTop) 
    Write-Host -NoNewline "Unzipping [$fold]..."$_
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping unhook my brain. I looked at this too many times.